# Higher memory usage in Python Idle when compared with VSCode

Tags: python, memory, python-idle

I have been comparing algorithms for Fibonacci sequences and the memory usage of the two algorithms and noticed extra memory usage in idle when compared to vscode.

The code being run was:

```
import tracemalloc

def fib_with_cache(n: int) -> int:
    cache = [0] * (n+1)
    cache[1] = 1
    if n > 1:
        cache[2] = 1
    for number in range(3, n+1):
        cache[number] = cache[number-1] + cache[number-2]
    return cache[n]


def fib_without_cache(n: int) -> int:
    a = 1
    b = 1
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        for i in range(1, n+1):
            temp = a
            a = b
            b = temp + a
        return b


tracemalloc.start()
fib_with_cache(10)
print("With cache", tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())
tracemalloc.stop()

print()

tracemalloc.start()
fib_without_cache(10)
print("Without cache", tracemalloc.get_traced_memory())
tracemalloc.stop()
```

I first ran the code in idle and got the below output:

```
With cache (0, 168)

Without cache (456, 536)
```

I thought it odd and not at all as expected so tried in vscode and got:

```
With cache (0, 168)  

Without cache (0, 80)
```

Repeated tests showed the same results.  Swapping the order of the function calls also showed the second call in idle to use more memory:

```
Without cache (0, 80)

With cache (448, 616)
```

Could anyone shed any light on why the results show the additional use of memory in idle?  The code was run from the editor and output to shell/terminal.

Comment: When running in vscode and IDLE, are you using a python shell in both to execute the code or are you executing them as files? Or different for both?

Comment: you really need to explain exactly what you are doing. These are both text editors, although, they provide ways to run Python code. What happens if you just run the python script in a terminal?

Comment: I saved the code to `test.py`, ran `idle test.py`, selected _Run >> Run module_, and got numbers very similar to OP.

Comment: I can replicate via python vs idle shells. Also the tracemalloc snapshots are also unexpectedly (to me) different.  I will note that the idle snapshots also include threadding.py and idle.py in their results. Perhaps these additional components (and anything else idle is doing) are a factor here that tracemalloc is reporting on.

Comment: I called `fib_with_cache` twice and didn't see the problem (got the same numbers twice). Then deleted the body from both and the odd numbers showed up again.

Comment: IDLE runs your python code in a separate python.exe process along with some IDLE python code (idlelib.run).  I am sure that vscode does something different that does not involve extra python code.  If tracemalloc only traces memory allocated to run python code, this could explain at least some of the difference.

Comment: @tdelaney - That makes things even more interesting.  Just tried calling fib_with_cache twice and yes the output for tracemalloc was identical, the same happens when calling fib_without_cache twice.  I only get the extra memory usage when calling one then the other.  Even more confused now :-/